# How to calculate hours per date

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google-sheets-timestamp

I am trying to use A Google Sheet generated by Google Forms to track total attendance time in lab for a robotics team.  I have created a form with the following questions:

1. Checking in or Checking out
2. Check In Name
3. Check Out Name

After selecting the first option, the respondent is directed to select their name from a pulldown list of all members.  This generates a workbook similar to [this workbook](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MSndD8BvrIs6Qt8MaeyWISZgdFRpyYGq5Z-39qw3q2E/edit?usp=sharing).  The first sheet includes the responses with the timestamp which is important for recording times.  I am thinking the second sheet (Hours) could be used to summarize time.

Is it possible to use a combination of IF and VLOOKUP to calculate hours per day?  Or is there a more logical way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Make a pivot having team members as rows, Check in and Check out as columns and the put the timestamps con the corresponding intersections, them add a column to calculate the difference between both timestamps and display the result as hours.

There are several ways to do the above:

- Use a pivot table and a calculated field
- Use QUERY function to make the pivot then add a column to calculate the hours per day.
- Use a combinations of formulas to create the row / column headings, set the intersection values and to calculate the hours per day.